# Function Singularity in a Sobolev Space

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

For which $t$ and $p$ does function of the form 
$$ f(x) = 1/|x|^{\alpha} ,\quad 0<\alpha<1$$
belong to the fractional Sobolev space $H_p^t(\mathbb{R})$, $p>1,t\geq 0$?

UPD: actually I am intersted in
$$ f(x) = \chi_{[-1,1]}/|x|^{\alpha} ,\quad 0<\alpha<1$$ where $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ is a characteristic function of the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi I have changed a bit the question, maybe not it looks more reasonable.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Basically I just don't know how to compute the inverse Fourier transform of $(1+|\xi|^2)^{t/2} |\xi|^{-1+\alpha}$